# Limiting number of logged in users on .NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have done a fair amount of research on how to limit amount of users that can login into an application. Now I've seen people mentioning cookie-based checkups to see how many users are logged into the account but I haven't seen any implementation where I could see how that works exactly.

Besides that I'm wondering if there is already implemented solution of this in .NET MVC 5?

My final goal is  following:

- Only two users can login on one account
- If third user logs in, the first one that logged in should be kicked out of the system automatically

Can someone help me out with this one ?

Best regards

Comment: Why can you not add IP based check - allow only 2 IPs for 1 active login.  Have you tried this ? Is there any challenge in this approach ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari how exactly would I do this ?  Could you show me a practical implementation ?

Comment: Why would you want to limit the number of users? The person kicked off is going to be annoyed, then login again. Now, their co-worker is kicked off. And the cycle continues. Eventually, no-one is going to be doing anything other than logging in.

Comment: @mjwills Because one account is supposed to be used by 1 and only one person ? :D

Comment: Honestly, this is going to be very frustrating for your end-users. What does it achieve, in real terms? If you are worried about multiple operations at once - this won't help (one single person can open multiple browser tabs and do multiple things at once anyway). If you **do** do this, it makes more sense to not let the third person in (rather than kick the first person out). Otherwise, if you kick the logged in person out, they may have been halfway through an operation (e.g. filling in a long form) and lose all of their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This check sounds similar to Netflix check - you  can login using only 5 devices. 
But there is limitation on devices - hence different sessions in same login ID can be identified using IP addresses and device information in HTTP packet.

This is very nice code sample.

IsUserLoggedInElsewhere will check the logins from other places.

Instead of log everyone else out you will have to log out the first user based on login time whenever third user logs in using same account.

Please [refer this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/589440/How-To-Prevent-the-Same-User-ID) for more details about this.

```
public static bool IsYourLoginStillTrue(string userId, string sid)
{
    CapWorxQuikCapContext context = new CapWorxQuikCapContext();

    IEnumerable<Logins> logins = (from i in context.Logins
                                    where i.LoggedIn == true && 
                                    i.UserId == userId && i.SessionId == sid
                                    select i).AsEnumerable();
    return logins.Any();
}

public static bool IsUserLoggedOnElsewhere(string userId, string sid)
{
    CapWorxQuikCapContext context = new CapWorxQuikCapContext();

    IEnumerable<Logins> logins = (from i in context.Logins
                                    where i.LoggedIn == true && 
                                    i.UserId == userId && i.SessionId != sid
                                    select i).AsEnumerable();
    return logins.Any();
}

public static void LogEveryoneElseOut(string userId, string sid)
{
    CapWorxQuikCapContext context = new CapWorxQuikCapContext();

    IEnumerable<Logins> logins = (from i in context.Logins 
                                    where i.LoggedIn == true && 
                                    i.UserId == userId && 
                                    i.SessionId != sid // need to filter by user ID
                                    select i).AsEnumerable();

    foreach (Logins item in logins)
    {
        item.LoggedIn = false;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done by one of two ways:

1 : by data base
-- Add a field in users table refer to **login_status** (Bool)- and **Last_login_Time** (Date)
-- Change **login_status** to (True) and **Last_login_Time** to dateTime.now
-- Before login get from **Users** table number of users with **login_status** true
-- if count less than two ..normal login
-- if count more than = 2 end session for user with earlier login time and set current user is logged..

2 - Also it can be done by using global variables in Global.asax and

Comment: could you show me a piece of code on how it can be done in Global.asax ?

Comment: Manoj mentioned IP based checks, does your implementation includes that ? :)